# Redux state observer to return desired state

Tags: javascript, redux

I have function which observes state and allows us to run onChange function when selector state changes.

```js
function observeStore(store, select, onChange) {
  let currentState;

  function handleChange() {
    let nextState = select(store.getState());
    if (nextState !== currentState) {
      currentState = nextState;
      onChange(currentState)
    }
  }

  let unsubscribe = store.subscribe(handleChange);
  handleChange();
  return unsubscribe;
}
```

This is how I can use it

```js
observeStore(store, selectedProductIdSelector, state => {
   console.log('state changes', state) // 10
})
```

This will become a problem if I want to observe multiple states. So, is there a way we can edit observer function in order to call it like below...

```js
const productId = observeStore(store, selectedProductIdSelector)
console.log(productId) // 10
```

Comment: Are you using just javascript vanilla and redux ?

Comment: There's a use case in my application where I have to use redux state outside react components. And want to observe it so I can have the latest state after applying a selector.

Comment: Here's the code sandbox link to further explain it in much detail.
https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-herschel-2oeue